# Ajax click event not firing In Javascript File

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, onclicklistener

So i have a table in jsp and i'm trying to fire a function when clicking on the table lines in order to post the data.
I have a JS file where i creted my function with ajax click event
problem is the event is not firing

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click",'.outi',(function(MyObj)
    {   var Myjson = JSON.stringify(MyObj); 
         $.ajax({
             // Methode POST
             method: "POST",
             // URL
             url: "Client_frameServlet",
             // Mode asynchrone pour attendre la fin de l'ajax avant de continuer
             async: false, // Mode synchrone
             // Envoie des donnees
             data: Myjson ,
             //data: {user: document.princ_form.user.value, numero_carte: document.princ_form.password_old.value, password_n1: document.princ_form.password_n1.value},
             dataType: "json" ,
             success: function() {
            alert('In Ajax');
        }
             
         })
    }));
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    
    <html>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="0">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="iso-8859-1">
    <head>
      <title>TX06</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
      <script src="date.js"></SCRIPT>
    </head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
               ></script>
    <script src="res_gen.js">
    
    </script>
    <body>
     
      <table width="100%" align="center" border=0 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
              <table width="95%" align="center" border=0 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td class="titre">Résultat de la recherche</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <br>
    <table border=0 bgcolor=#92ADC2 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3 width=95% align=center>
        <tr class=entete>
            <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Nom</td>
            <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Date de naissance</td>
            <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Coll</td>
            <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Numéro</td>
            <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Numéro contact</td>     
            <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;TITULAIRE</td>
        </tr>
        
                <tr class="outi" onMouseOver="this.className='over';" onMouseOut="this.className='outi';">
                    <td class=texte7 align=left colspan=5>&nbsp;Aucun client ne trouve</td>
                </tr>
            
    </table>
    
    <br>
    <table width="95%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <a target="corps" href="gen_rech.jsp" class="rub2" onmouseover="voltar.src = '../images/fr/voltar_s.gif';" onmouseout="voltar.src = '../images/fr/voltar.gif';"><img src="../images/fr/voltar.gif" border="0" name=voltar ></a>
        </td>
      </tr> 
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

PS: i already tried calling by classname it's not working
And checked to browser params to see that it's actually not fired

Comment: The HTML (and JavaScript) shown is malformed and invalid.  Can you update this to a runnable [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/328193) which demonstrates the problem?  (JSP doesn't seem to be involved here at all if the problem is purely client-side, you can use the resulting HTML on your page to demonstrate the problem.)

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding, i edited the code and put the html shown in the browser, sam for the js file

Comment: The code snippet is producing an error.  It would appear that there is extra code included which relies on code which is not included.  The example should be a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  Alternatively, if the error shown here is also occurring in your own project, then resolving that error (and any others you're seeing) would be your first step.

Comment: I edited the code removing part not needed in this issue, the code snippet is runnnig now, have you any idea what my ajax event not firign problem can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the element(s) you're filtering on in your click handler:

```
$(document).on("click", '.outi', (function(MyObj){
```

The handler function will specifically execute for elements with the `outi` class.  But your element doesn't *have* that class.

It does when the page first loads:

```
<tr class="outi" onMouseOver="this.className='over';" onMouseOut="this.className='outi';">
```

But notice what the inline JavaScript on that element is doing.  When the mouse hovers over the element, it *changes the class*.

The mouse is going to hover over the element before the user clicks the element.

You can target the class it actually has:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", '.over', (function(MyObj){
    console.log('test');
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<table border=0 bgcolor=#92ADC2 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3 width=95% align=center>
  <tr class=entete>
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Nom</td>
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Date de naissance</td>
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Collaborateur</td>
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Numéro de la carte</td>
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Numéro de contrat</td>      
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;TITULAIRE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="outi" onMouseOver="this.className='over';" onMouseOut="this.className='outi';">
    <td class=texte7 align=left colspan=5>&nbsp;Aucun client ne trouve</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or perhaps use *both* classes instead of replacing one with the other:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", '.outi', (function(MyObj){
    console.log('test');
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<table border=0 bgcolor=#92ADC2 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3 width=95% align=center>
  <tr class=entete>
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Nom</td>
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Date de naissance</td>
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Collaborateur</td>
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Numéro de la carte</td>
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;Numéro de contrat</td>      
    <td class=texte8 align=center>&nbsp;TITULAIRE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="outi" onMouseOver="this.classList.add('over');" onMouseOut="this.classList.remove('over');">
    <td class=texte7 align=left colspan=5>&nbsp;Aucun client ne trouve</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However you approach it, the main point is that when you're filtering on a specific class then the element needs to have that class to trigger the event handler.